How can one display an array (from a shapefile) as a gradient without the images pixel cells 'dimming' when zoomed out?
I have a shapefile that contains a value 'carbon'. This field contains values from -130 to 130.
Symbology settings:
Graduated
Value: Carbon
Color ramp: spectral
Classes: Equal Count
When I am zoomed in, the image looks like this

But when I zoom out, the image is dimmed, like this

This is undesirable, because the differentiation in carbon amounts becomes extremely difficult to visualize. Is there a way to work around this issue? What causes the image to dim when zoomed out?

Draw polygons without (black/grey) borders

Thanks for the answer. Is this something that I can change in the symbology settings? I see under symbol that I can change the "Fill" to line pattern fill and this definitely brightens up the image.
Where can I find that option concerning the borders? Or is this something to do with the importing of the shapefile?

This is a pure symbplogy, not data, issue. I don't QGIS, but I'm quite certain you can specify that the boundary line not be rendered (or be rendered 100% transparent).. Note that an Answer occurs down below. These are comments. Please take the [Tour] to better understand how things work here. Welcome to GIS SE.

Remove the polygon outlines:

Open Layer properties and click Symbology
Click Symbol

Click Simple Fill

Change Stroke Style to No Line

Result



this is it! thanks so much :)

done :) thank you for helping me learn how things work here! great website!
